# how can i override importexport adminhtml block?

Tags: magento-1.8

i want to rewrite importexport block of admin panel, but it's in app > code > core > mage > importexport > Block > Adminhtml so i am confuse about that how to rewrite if adminhtml block is not in app > code > core > mage > Adminhtml

i have added in config.xml

```
 <importexport>
       <rewrite> 
            <adminhtml_import_edit>cNAme_mName_Block_Adminhtml_Import_Edit</adminhtml_import_edit>
      </rewrite>
    </importexport>
```

--------------------------AND---------------------------------------

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
      <rewrite>
        <import_edit>cName_mName_Block_Adminhtml_Import_Edit</_import_edit>
      </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

but it's not work for me.

i have rewriting other block like.

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Form.php

using

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite><catalog_product_grid>cName_mName_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Hi sandeep and welcome to magento.stackexchange. If this code is inside <blocks> it looks fine. Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back.

Comment: Hi Fabian Blechschmidt,
Thanks for replay. Tt's in <blocks> tag. but it's not working.

Comment: The error indicates that you have a bigger problem, than the rewrite. Do you have a website with the code www? Whatever is happening, I don't think it is about the rewrite. Check the tutorial! Happy digging.

Comment: but when i remove rewrite code, site work fine. so i think i missing something in class name or config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create in `app/local` folder a new folder `Mage/ImportExport/Block/Adminhtml/Import`, then copy there the original `Mage_ImportExport_Block_Adminhtml_Import_Edit` file and modify it as you wish (the classname remains the same as the original). It will override the original file without *any* `config.xml` changes (so you can remove the related rewrite rules).

Comment: Thanks Zsolti
i try your suggestion with some changes and it's work.